# MS SQL Linked Server Timeouts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting SQL linked server timeout errors however they are not always the same:

> linked server "(null)" returned message "Query timeout expired". while
>   other times linked server "(LinkedServerName)" returned message "Query
>   timeout expired".

Is there a reason I would get an error where the linked server name is "**null**"? When would I get a `null` name vs the real linked server name?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you quering an excell file?  How are you running the query and what is your linked server?

Comment: I am selecting data into a temp table from a permanent table but the data is coming from a linked sql server. such as:
select * into #temptable from LinkedServer.mydatabase.dbo.mytable

Comment: Can you run any queries on the linked server?  select * from linkedserver.master.sys.databases?

Comment: Yeah, most of the time it seems to work properly and once in a while I get the error. What I'm most curious about is why it says null in the place where I expect it to tell me the linked server name, I'm guessing that there is a network issue of some sort that occurs randomly, but would like confirmation.

Comment: Isn't always network.  I got this error based on drivers trying to connect to excel.  Check out this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/83300532-e780-4ac6-9a64-7246e58c253a/linked-server-using-microsoftjetoledb40-problem